# How to refer to the previous situation?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

> I don't want to create a situation which was there last time

This doesn't sound idiomatic? How to make it better?

Comment: You can significantly shorten the sentence by saying "I don't want to *recreate* the situation...".

Comment: **or**, I don't want to create the **same** situation again!

Comment: @Stephie can I say: How about - I don't want to create a situation like before?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius : Yup, that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to create a situation *like* last time.

You could also use *similar to*:

> I don't want to create a situation *similar to* last time.